# Redirect passing url parameters to state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using: "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"

I am navigating to an url:

http://localhost:3000/#id_token=123&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

I have a Redirect component ready to catch that and redirect me to dashboard:

```
<Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
```

I know that we can redirect and pass state to props (from react-router docs) like this:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/dashboard",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```

However, I am not sure how to pass parameters from url to state (id_token, expires_in, etc.)

What is the solution to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract the URL parameters before the redirect and them pass them in the Redirect route state

`window.location.hash` will give you the informtaion in your url - [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash). You can create a util function to parse your hash and return to you the keys and values. You can then pass that in the Redirect

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/dashboard",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { id_token, expires_in, token_type  }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! window.location.hash is exactly what I needed.